# Problem with execute command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a clock leading into this command:

```
/execute @e[type=Chicken] ~ ~ ~ tp @p [team=t1] ~ ~33 ~
```

but when i spawn a chicken, nothing happens.  The previous output box says:

```
[11:22:54] Failed to execute 'tp @p [team=t1] ~ ~33 ~' as Chicken
```

What am i doing wrong and how can i fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, i realised that there shouldn't be a space between `@p` and `[team=t1]`